# Laravel + React - Initial Input State Failing Validation

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I am fairly new to Laravel and React and I seem to be having an issue.

I have a form where the input state is initialized with these values

```
const empty = {
    name: '',
    email: '',
    phone: '',
    topic: '',
    message: '',
};

const [input, setInput] = useState(empty);

const handleChange = (e) => setInput({
    ...input,
    [e.currentTarget.name]: e.currentTarget.value
});

<input 
    name="phone" 
    type="text" 
    className={ input_classes }
    onChange={ handleChange }
    value={ input.phone }
/>
{
  errors.phone !== null &&
  <InputError message={ errors.phone } />
}
```

So my issue comes when its time to submit this form. All fields other than phone are required. Here are the *current* validation rules for this form

```
    request()->validate([
        'name' => 'bail|required|max:255',
        'email' => 'bail|required|email',
        'phone' => 'numeric',
        'topic' => 'bail|required|max:255',
        'message' => 'required',
    ]);
```

Submitting the form with all but the phone entered results in the server sending a 422 with error message that phone must be numeric. I understand that this has to do with initializing the input state as `''`.

Am I handling this incorrectly on the react side? attempting to initialize the state with `undefined` or `null` values has not been successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have to declare your rule as `nullable` too.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-nullable

So, basically:

```
'phone' => 'numeric|nullable',
```